# php create cookie not working in if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have a php code

```
$cookie_name = "John";
$cookie_age = "28";

   setcookie("nameee", $cookie_name, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
   setcookie("ageee", $cookie_age, time()+3600, "/", "",  0);
```

When this code is used in independent file it works. But when it is used in if else statement as given below it does not work

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM regusers WHERE email='$email' AND password='$upass' AND active=1"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

//If count is 0 , then enter the values
if($count=="0"){ 
$error = "Email or Password does not Match !";
}

else if($count!="0")
 {

$cookie_name = "John";
$cookie_age = "28";

   setcookie("nameee", $cookie_name, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
   setcookie("ageee", $cookie_age, time()+3600, "/", "",  0);


$error = "Login Successful. Redirecting to admin page  !";
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'document.location.href="cpanel.php"';
echo '</script>';



 } 


 // else update the values 
 else {

}
```

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi there! Everything else works? i.e. you see the "Login successful" message and are redirected to "cpanel.php"?

Comment: I think the if/else statement not working as intended is the least of your worries, though to debug it just var_dump($count); to see what its contents are.

I would be more worried about how vulnerable this script is to SQL injection as well as using depreciated methods and extensions.

Comment: i want to create cookie along with redirection to cpanel.php